# script - click button every x seconds

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I want a script that clicks on this button every 3 seconds

`<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Puxar Alavanca">`

It dsnt have any class, can you guys help me?

Comment: Look into `setInterval`.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I have added a random time between 3 and 4 seconds as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery to trigger a click event'

```
setInterval(function(){
   $( "input" ).trigger("click");
},random(3000,4000));

function random(min,max){
   return min + (max - min) * Math.random()
}
```

Comment: This worked but, how to put a random time from 3s to 4s?

Just to make sure the game won't ban me :D

Comment: @FranciscoRibeiro See the updated, mark my solution as correct solution if that solve your problem

Comment: What does it click on? How do you target the id and/or class (or other element)? Add some xpath and some explanation please.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it

```
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="but" value="Puxar Alavanca">

    var but = document.querySelector("[name='Submit']");
    setInterval(function () {but.click();},3000);
```

You can visit this link to know more https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: 2 problems. An additional id changes the problem definition and actual time should be 3000 ms. Good work otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setInterval() method`.`document.querySelector()` selects your element,the `setInterval() clicks` button on every 3 seconds and the click event is handled by a `function`.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("[name='Submit']");
//console.log(btn);
setInterval(function(){
btn.click();
},3000);

//Handling of click event
btn.onclick=function(){ 
console.log('clicked');
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Puxar Alavanca">
```

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a class name and such, you are going to want to make sure you only click the button you want when doing this.

With my version, it allows for gathering all the tags of type '*input*' and clicking the one you requested ***only*** - every 3-4 (***this number is randomly generated, sometimes 3 sometimes 4***) seconds.

Please see below:

```js
// Random time between 3 and 4 seconds.
var randomTime = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 3 + 1)) + 3) * 1000;    

setInterval(function() {    
  var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    if (tags[i].value == "Puxar Alavanca") {
      tags[i].click();
      
      // Below alert should be removed, just for testing/showing purposes.
      alert("Button clicked after " + randomTime + "ms.");
    }
  }
}, randomTime);
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Puxar Alavanca">
```

Comment: Suggesting 3000 instead of 1000 ms.

Comment: Thanks! I meant to put that but just had it at 1000 for testing. Just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var interval = 1000; // Click interval in milliseconds

function clickButton() {
   var button = document.getElementById('buttonId'); // Replace 'buttonId' with the ID of the button you want to click
   button.click();
}

setInterval(clickButton, interval);
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you [edit] your post to explain why it answer to the oP?